# Install Windows Server AppFabric Cache on multiple instances of Azure Web / Worker Roles

Tags: azure, appfabric

Is there any way I can install the Windows Server AppFabric Cache (not the Azure version mind you) to Azure Web Roles / Worker Roles such that I can make use of the free memory I get on these instead of paying for Azure AppFabric Cache which is expensive and has a limit of 8MB per object (which does not work for my scenario)

I would prefer Windows Server AppFabric Cache on Azure over memcached on Azure primarily due to legacy code which uses Windows Server AppFabric Cache

Answer (score 2):

If you can do the installation with a batch file, then you can make it a [startup task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) of your role.

Comment: looks like a pain in the arse for sure :-)